# Project builder is not in correct order (should be after scala builder) for project <project name>

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, scala-ide

I can see below message in Problems tab in my **Eclipse**(**Scala** IDE build of Eclipse), even though maven build(clean install) is successful. But am not able to execute main method because of this error. Please help.

> Project builder is not in correct order (should be after scala
>   builder) for project , and problem type - Scalastyle
>   problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the project builder order of a project:

1. **Right-click project** folder and choose ***Properties***
2. In ***Builder*** select a builder and click ***Up*** or ***Down***